# Removing files in a folder with specific pattern

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, filesystems

I have 20 Files in a folder. 10 files naming pattern is PTT-20190118-WA0010.wav and other 10 files naming pattern is PTT-20190118-WA0010_s.wav.

How to delete files with "PTT-20190118-WA0010.wav" pattern with single command ?

Comment: can you share all or few file names with `PTT-20190118-WA0010.wav` pattern

Comment: PTT-20190118-WA0010.wav, PTT-20190118-WA0011.wav, PTT-20190118-WA0012.wav, PTT-20190118-WA0013.wav   Only last two digits are changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any other matching files you can use

```
rm PTT-*[0-9].wav
```

or even

```
rm *[0-9].wav
```

assuming all file names without `_s` end with a digit before `.wav`.

I suggest to try with `echo` instead of `rm` first or use `rm -i` to get a confirmation request for every file to avoid accidentally removing the wrong files.

Comment: @ViralParmar If the answer is what you need you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 rm -f PTT-20190118-WA001[0-9].wav
```